# How can I determine whether a string is in a variable using an if statement?

Tags: perl, if-statement

I'm currently learning Perl and I'm trying to figure out how to do an 
`if string in variable { do stuff`
}

I've tried many different ways such as using the eq, and =~ but it returns all the keywords within keywords.txt in oppose to the specific keyword that's found in $line

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $keywords = 'keywords.txt';
open( my $kw, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $keywords )
   or die "Could not open file '$keywords' $!"
   ;    # Open the file, throw an exception if the file cannot be opened.
chomp( my @keywordsarray = <$kw> )
   ;           # Remove whitespace, and read it into an array
close($kw);    # Close the file

my $syslog = 'syslog';
open( my $sl, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $syslog )
   or die "Could not open file '$keywords' $!"
   ;           # Open the file, throw an exception if the file cannot be opened.
chomp( my @syslogarray = <$sl> ); # Remove whitespace, and read it into an array
close($sl);                       # Close the file

foreach my $line (@syslogarray) {
   foreach my $keyword (@keywordsarray) {
      if ( $keyword =~ $line ) {
         print "**" . $keyword . "**" . "\n";
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
while (my $line = <$sl>) {
   for my $keyword (@keywordsarray) {
      if ( $line =~ /\b\Q$keyword\E\b/ ) {
         print "**$keyword** $line";
      }
   }
}
```

I used `\b` so that the line `abandoned` isn't considered to include the keyword `band`. Note that my use of `\b` assumes your keywords all start and end with a word character. Something else needs to be used if that that's not the case.

But that's super slow. You're compiling number_of_lines * number_of_keywords regular expressions. The following only compiles one. It also greatly reduces the number of matches performed.

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @keywordsarray;
my $re = qr/\b($pat)\b/;

while (my $line = <$sl>) {
   while ($line =~ /$re/g) {
      print "**$1** $line";
   }
}
```

If you just need to know whether a line matched or not, then you simple need

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @keywordsarray;
my $re = qr/\b(?:$pat)\b/;

while (<$sl>) {
   print if /$re/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

```
...
if ( $line =~ m/\Q$keyword\E/ ) { 
   ... 
}
...
```

this would the be *a* correct check to determine if the text inside of the variable `$keyword` occurs somewhere in `$line`;

The `\Q` and `\E` flags indicate that no special characters that occur within the text of `$keyword` should be interpreted. You can read more about Perl regular expression flags in [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

EDIT: as @ikegami points out, without using `\b` to indicate a word break the pattern above can give false positives.

Comment: If you go with this approach, you should consider pre-compiling your regular expression ahead of time as @ikegami suggests below

Comment: Note that this will consider the line "abandoned" to include the keyword "band". That's why I used `\b`